# Why the candles in candlelight vigils?

Tags: symbols

[Hundreds Gather At ‘Stop Asian Hate’ Candlelight Vigil In Alhambra](https://losangeles.cbslocal.com/2021/03/20/stop-asian-hate-candlelight-vigil-scheduled-in-alhambra-on-saturday/)

In today's world it's surely easy to have illumination at night, so there should be no need for candlelight vigils when one could equally have electric light vigils. Do the candles in candlelight vigils have any symbolism?

Comment: In today's world we have candles, so there should be no need to have electric light vigils. It's not about providing a source of illumination: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oARpBM5lG3Q

Comment: What are the candles for then?

Comment: I looked up the Wikipedia article on candlelight vigils. It gave a passable description of what they were, but not about why it’s a popular political tactic.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm the Wikipedia article has a notation at the top. The whole article is about a specific incident, not a discussion of the term. Quora's [When was the first candlelight vigil done?](https://www.quora.com/When-was-the-first-candlelight-vigil-done) explores but there's nothing conclusive. There seems to be an association with religious/spiritual associates with a candle flame. It seems that the use of a candle is *symbolic* rather than a practical source of ambient illumination.

Comment: Candles are an ancient (*ancient*) metaphor for the human soul or spirit: the way they flicker and move almost as if they were alive. Candlelight vigils represent souls reaching out to souls. No one is likely to perceive an electric light as akin to a soul; they are too static and mechanical.

Comment: Given that candlelight vigils are often used political purposes, I do not see why this is outside scope. Voting to reopen.

Comment: I agree with Ted. There’s no political purpose here. It’s a candlelight vigil for people who were murdered, not a candlelight rally. Find an example where candles are used in a political sense and I’ll vote to reopen

Comment: @divibisan https://www.abc.net.au/news/2021-03-21/myanmar-activists-hold-candle-lit-vigils-as-four-more-killed/100020100 Like this?

Comment: Or this? https://www.uniglobalunion.org/fr/node/38022 Or this? https://www.nzherald.co.nz/world/hong-kong-activists-hold-tiananmen-candlelight-vigil/3H6ANE3COQQ3PC6YFPCJLFL7GY/ Or Google for "candlelight vigil politics" and see what pops up.

Comment: @Allure: candlelight vigils aren't expressly political, though (like any symbology) they can be used within politics. This would be better asked on a stack related to sociology than here, because the answer is sociological, cultural, or psychological, not political.

Comment: @TedWrigley: Well, the reasoning that holding a candle prevents demonstrators from engaging in certain violent behaviour (due to both hands being occupied) *might* be somehow political, but it doesn't quite fit the question as currently asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Candles only burn for a limited maximum time, symbolizing the general brevity of human life.
2. Candles can easily be extinguished well before that maximum, emphasizing the particular and unfortunate brevity of those human lives being commemorated.
3. Candles give less light at night than electric light, and hence allow more darkness, and provide a given scene greater artistic "negative space"; this negative space symbolizes the greater darkness of the mind or spirit, (*i.e.* intellectual, civic, and moral ignorance), against which these vigils protest.
4. Candles are prettier.  Imagine any such vigil, and imagine replacing each candle with LED candle shaped Christmas lights -- ugh!